# Rules: conjunctive adverbs

Tags: sentence-construction, adverbs, conjunctions

Below is a sentence from yourdictionary.com

> There has been an increase in greenhouse gases, therefore global warming is happening. (Depending on a writer)

Which can be rewritten as:

1)- There has been an increase in greenhouse gases; therefore, global warming is happening.

Or

2)- There has been an increase in greenhouse gases. Therefore, global warming is happening.

Please confirm if above two sentences can be rewritten as a replacement of original one.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to fix the sentence with *therefore* :

**1** - Make the clause beginning with therefore as a separate sentence. **There has been an increase in greenhouse gases. Therefore, global warming is happening**

**2** - Use a semicolon instead of a comma. ( to introduce a new independent clause) **There has been an increase in greenhouse gases; therefore, global warming is happening**

**3** - Use commas around both sides of *therefore* if it is used as an intensifier or for emphasis **There has been an increase in greenhouse gases, therefore, global warming is happening**

**4** - Or you can add a conjunction to link the two independent clauses.**There has been an increase in greenhouse gases, and therefore global warming is happening**